# How do you create local branches without getting the uncommited changes of other local branches?

Tags: git

I'm currently working on multiple changes/bugs and I would like to be able to work on these individually using individual local branches.  But when I am in the middle of working on something on for example `branch_a` and then I need to start work on a new hot project, and I create a `branch_b`, I still have the changes that I made from `branch_a`.

Here is the workflow:

1. Created and checked-out local `branch_a` from `dev` branch
2. Made local changes to `branch_a` (but no staging via `git add` or commits locally)
3. Needed to start on a new hot bug so switched to `dev` branch, and created and checked-out `branch_b`
4. Perform a `git status` and I see the changes I made on `branch_a`

How do I create a new branch that doesn't have the changes I made on `branch_a`?

Also, when I checkout another branch I get

```
$ git checkout branch_b
M   app/controllers/stuff.rb
M   app/views/stuff/index.html.erb
Switched to branch 'branch_b'
```

What does the `M` represent?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The M means modified. First you have to commit your changes to your current branch or stash them.

When you want to stash them:

```
git add .
# temporary stash your changes
git stash
# create a new branch
git checkout -b branch_b
# do your changes
git commit -am 'fixed but in branch_b'
# go back to branch a
git checkout branch_a
# get back your stash
git stash pop
```

When you choose to commit your changes:

```
git add .
git commit -am 'changes in branch_a'
# creating and checkout new branch
git checkout -b branch_b
# fix your bug
git add .
git commit -am 'just fixed a bug'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `M` is modified. You've modified that file, and it's unstaged. You can either add the modifications and then commit them as a work in progress in `branch_a` before swapping to your new branch, or Use `git stash` to stash the changes before swapping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your uncomitted changes somewhere. That is, unless you want to just get rid of them, but you probably don't want to do that.

The best solution here is almost certainly [`git stash`](http://book.git-scm.com/4_stashing.html). This lets you "stash" your uncomitted changes so you can work with a fresh working copy, and then you can reapply your stash later.

Answer (score 0):

The `M` represents that the file was Modified. To do what you want, there are two approaches I typically use.

One approach is using the stash, call `git stash` before you leave the current branch and all of your changes will be put into a 'secondary index' of sorts called the stash. When you get back to your original branch just call `git stash pop` to pull the changes back off of the stash.

Another approach which I also use fairly frequently if I anticipate my new set of changes will be fairly long-lived, is to just make a "wip" commit which I revert later:

```
(oldbranch)$ git add -A . && git commit -m"wip"
(oldbranch)$ git checkout master && git checkout -b newbranch
# work on the new branch....
(newbranch)$ git checkout oldbranch
(newbranch)$ git reset HEAD^
```

The `git reset HEAD^` reverts your working directory to the commit BEFORE the current head of the branch, and moves all of the changes that were part of that "wip" commit back into your working directory, effectively setting you back where you were.